# Select immediate first Div element inside div if first element not p

Tags: html, css, styles

I want to select first child element inside a div irrespective of the element(If it div then also and if it is p or other element then also) inside my stylesheet (CSS).

```
<div class="mainInterview">
    <p></p>
    <div class="gallery"></div>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <div class="gallery"></div>
    <div class="gallery"></div>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <div class="gallery"></div>
    <div class="gallery"></div>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

OR the code could be

```
<div class="mainInterview">
    <div class="gallery"></div>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <div class="gallery"></div>
    <div class="gallery"></div>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <div class="gallery"></div>
    <div class="gallery"></div>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

If the immediate first element if .gallery then only i need to write some styles. Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: CSS only or JS?

Comment: If it is in css then it will be helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the :first-child selector without specifying the element type of the selected child, adding gallery class selector to it:

```
.mainInterview > :first-child.gallery {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Here is a Tryit Editor example:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FJDQK638Z9JG

Comment: I want to select only if the first child is .gallery @Kristóf Kőhalmy

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem at first - I updated my answer and the example. Now you can select the .gallery element if and only if it is first child of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
.mainInterview > div:nth-of-type(1){
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: red;
}
```